# Two images inside minipage (side by side) with one common caption that says "Figure 1 & 2:"

Tags: graphics, captions, minipage

I have two images inside a `minipage`, so I can have them side by side. When I make a caption for the images it only comes up as "figure 3: text", but I would like to have it showing  "Figure 3 & 4: text".

I tried to `\end{figure}` and `\begin{figure}` in each `minipage` but the images would not show side by side anymore. The code I have at the moment is:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.58]{fig1}
\end{minipage} \hspace{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.58]{fig2}
\end{minipage}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You don't need the minipage there you can just use two `\includegraphics`

Answer (score 6):

This isn't quite what you've asked for, but how about the following? I'm using the `subcaption` package to put your two pictures into two 'subfigures'. The pictures can then be referenced individually (Figure 1a and Figure 1b), or as a pair (Figure 1).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.58]{fig1}
        \caption{horse}
        \label{fig:horse}
    \end{subfigure} \hspace{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.58]{fig2}
        \caption{zebra}
        \label{fig:zebra}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{animals}
\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{fig:animals} shows some animals. Figure~\ref{fig:horse} shows a horse.

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, some conference templates explicitly throw an error when `subcaption` is loaded. People have to use `minipage`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{dummy}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.58]{fig1}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.2\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2}
\end{minipage}%
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure} \& %
  \setcounter{dummy}{\arabic{figure}}%
  \protect\stepcounter{dummy}\arabic{dummy}}%
\caption{text}
\stepcounter{figure}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.58]{fig1}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. Despite of working fine, there is an error which says "Undefined control sequence \caption{". I tried to play with the packages and see if there was a crash between them, but so far no luck. Do you know why is it showing this error? Thanks once again.

Comment: difficult to say. A `\caption` command is defined in nearly all documentclasses

Comment: I'd refresh very old question.

To eliminate the error from Herbert's answer, you also need to protect `\setcounter`:

`\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure} \& %
\protect\setcounter{dummy}{\arabic{figure}}%
\protect\stepcounter{dummy}\arabic{dummy}}%`